# Javascript convert string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, structure

I have a string of the following format, how do I convert this string into an array of arrays so I can easily access the items?

```
data = '[[Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16]]'
```

I have tried `Array.from(data)` but it didn't work!

TIA

Comment: transform the string to JSON and use this `let dataArray = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Change the format of the string to json >.<

Comment: how are you getting that string? if you're hardcoding it, then hard code it better, if you're sending that from an API you wrote, then make the API send JSON ... otherwise, just hard code what you need - last option, parse the string in code, but writing a parser for that will be hard

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect but should get the jobs done:

```js
const data = '[[Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16]]';

const json = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\s*([^[\],]+?)\s*(?=[,\]])/g, '"$1"'));

console.log(json);
```

### How the regex works:

```
\s*([^[\],]+?)\s*(?=[,\]])
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/cFMpVf/1) you can see how it works and play around a little bit

| syntax | explain |
| --- | --- |
| `\s*` | any white spaces, this is for getting rid of the leading spaces from each entry |
| `(` | group one start, this is for capturing each entry, such as `Bday Party` |
| `[^[\],]+?` | 1 or more characters that does not contain `[`, `]` and `,`. `+?` means 1 or more but non-greedy, this is for avoiding capturing trailing spaces (we can't rule out white spaces inside of the character set, since some of the entries contains white spaces in the middle) |
| `)` | group one end, so far we have captured the entry we need in group one, such as `Bday Party` |
| `\s*` | any trailing whitespaces after an entry, we don't need that in our capturing group |
| `(?=[,\]])` | a lookahead, everything we have matched must be followed by a `,`(list separator) or `]`(end of an array) |

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain a little bit the regex part ? I am not OP and have really hard time with regexes

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Just did, hope it helps you to understand it a little bit.

Comment: thank you it is indeed detailed

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following string splitting approach:

```js
var data = '[[Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16]]';
data = data.substring(2, data.length - 2);
var array = data.match(/\[.*?\]/g);
var output = [];
for (var i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    output.push(array[i].substring(1, array[i].length - 1).split(/\s*,\s*/));
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many good suggestions involving regular expressions, but in case you find it easier with direct string manipulation, here's an example of that:

```js
var rawData = "[[Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16], [Bday Party , 2023-05-16]]";

var rows = rawData.slice(2, rawData.length - 2).split('], [');
var data = rows.map(x => x.split(", "));

console.log(data);
```

As with all answers, we don't know the definition of the format you're receiving, and it's not a standard one, so this snippet may not work on data with variations in structure.